# python & c-c++ extended module case segmentfault

Tags: python, c++, c

c++ code

```
extern "C" PyObject * test(){
    PyObject *oplist = PyList_New(10000);
    for(uint32_t j = 0; j < 10000; j++){
        PyObject* pTuple = PyTuple_New(3);
        assert(PyTuple_Check(pTuple));
        assert(PyTuple_Size(pTuple) == 3);
        PyTuple_SetItem(pTuple, 0, Py_BuildValue("s", "b"));
        PyTuple_SetItem(pTuple, 1, Py_BuildValue("i", 1)); 
        PyTuple_SetItem(pTuple, 2, Py_BuildValue("s", "a"));
        PyList_SetItem(oplist, j, pTuple);
    }    
    return oplist;
}
```

python code

```
LID = ctypes.CDLL('%s/token2map_lib.so' % '.')
LID.test.restype = py_object
LID.test()
```

build cmd

`g++ -fPIC token2map.cpp -I/usr/local/app/service/virtualenvs/NLP/include/python2.7 -shared -o token2map_lib.so`

i just show a part of code，forgive me and total code is to long

problem:
in c++ code，this function return res_list is smallar everything is ok. forever, result set is more than 215(j = 215) case segmentfalut. i can't find problem, hope present friend can give me some advise，i will very grateful.

i got a way to solution this problem

```
extern "C" PyObject * test(){
    PyGILState_STATE gstate = PyGILState_Ensure();
    PyObject *oplist = PyTuple_New(10000);
    for(int32_t j = 0; j < 10000; j++){
        PyObject * pTuple = PyTuple_New(3);
        assert(PyTuple_Check(pTuple));
        assert(PyTuple_Size(pTuple) == 3);
        PyTuple_SetItem(pTuple, 0, Py_BuildValue("s", "b"));
        PyTuple_SetItem(pTuple, 1, Py_BuildValue("i", 1)); 
        PyTuple_SetItem(pTuple, 2, Py_BuildValue("s", "a"));
        PyTuple_SetItem(oplist, j, pTuple);
    }    
    PyGILState_Release(gstate);
    return oplist;
}
```

but is there have anthor way to solution this problem? i don't think get GIL locak is a gool way

Comment: You're never checking the return value of **any** of these functions. As documented, you must **always** check **each and every single return value from each Python API function if it returns a value**.

Comment: And assertion is not a proper way to do the check.

Comment: In any case the question does not seem to have a [mre], including no explanation on how the function is even called, hence I am voting to close

Answer (score 1):

I can't give you an explanation as to why your code gives a seg fault. I do find it interesting that you were able to build your extension with a function that takes no parameters. I can, however provide code that does build and work:

```
#define Py_SSIZE_T_CLEAN
#include <Python.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

static PyObject *test(PyObject *self, PyObject *ignorethis)
{
    PyObject *oplist = PyList_New(10000);
    for(uint32_t j = 0; j < 10000; ++j){
        PyObject *pTuple = PyTuple_New(3);
        PyTuple_SetItem(pTuple, 0, Py_BuildValue("s", "b"));
        PyTuple_SetItem(pTuple, 1, Py_BuildValue("i", 1));
        PyTuple_SetItem(pTuple, 2, Py_BuildValue("s", "a"));
        PyList_SetItem(oplist, j, pTuple);
    }
    return oplist;
}

static PyMethodDef methods[] = {
    {"test", test, METH_NOARGS, "function given by so"}
};

static PyModuleDef foobar = {
    PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,
    "foobar",
    "so question module",
    -1,
    methods
};

PyMODINIT_FUNC PyInit_foobar(void){
    PyObject *module;
    module = PyModule_Create(&foobar);
    return module;
}

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

you can load this module with `import foobar` and then run with `foobar.test()`